# Python: Rearrange indices from np.where()

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to rearrange the indices in a tuple which was created with np.where.
The reason for this is, that I would like to apply values to a number of special position (a pipe) in a mesh, which were pre-selected. The values shall be applied in the direction of flow. The direction of flow is defined from top left to bottom left = from (3,0) to (3,6) to (7,6) to (7,0). Currently, the order of the index tuple `ind` is according to the automatic sorting of the indices. This leads to the figure, below, where the values `1:10` are correctly applied, but 11:17 are obviously in reverse order.

Is there a better way to grab the indices or how can I rearrange the tuple so that the values are applied in the direction of flow?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# mesh size
nx, ny = 10, 10

# special positions
sx1, sx2, sy = .3, .7, .7

T = 1

# create mesh
u0 =  np.zeros((nx, ny))

# assign values to mesh
u0[int(nx*sx1), 0:int(ny*sy)] = T
u0[int(nx*sx2), 0:int(ny*sy)] = T
u0[int(nx*sx1+1):int(nx*sx2), int(ny*sy-1)] = T

# get indices of special positions
ind = np.where(u0 == T)

# EDIT: hand code sequence
length = len(u0[int(nx*sx2), 0:int(ny*sy)])
ind[0][-length:] = np.flip(ind[0][-length:])
ind[1][-length:] = np.flip(ind[1][-length:])

# apply new values on special positions
u0[ind] = np.arange(1, len(ind[1])+1,1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig = ax.imshow(u0, cmap=plt.get_cmap('RdBu_r'))
ax.figure.colorbar(fig)
plt.show()
```

Old image (without edit)
[image: Old image (without edit)]

New image (after edit)
[image: New image (after edit)]

Comment: *The values shall be applied in the direction of flow*, how do you define the *direction of flow*?

Comment: I edited the question. The direction of flow is defined from top left to bottom left = from (3,0) to (3,6) to (7,6) to (7,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a fallacy to think that you can algorithmically deduce the correct "flow-sequence" of the grid points, by examining the contents of the tuple `ind`.

Here's an example that illustrates why:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
A B C D E 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 F 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 G 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 I H 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 J K 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is a schematic representation of your grid matrix, where, if you follow the letters `A`, `B`, `C`, etc, you will get the sequence of the flow through the grid-elements.

However, note that, no matter how smart an algorithm is, it will be unable to choose between the two possible flows:

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`

and

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `K`, `J`, `I`

So, I think you will have to record the sequence explicitly yourself, rather than deduce it from the positions of the `T` values in the grid.

Any algorithm will stop at the ambiguity at the grid location `H` in the above example

Comment: I see what you mean. So I have to code it like that:
`length = len(u0[int(nx*sx2), 0:int(ny*sy)])`

`ind = np.where(u0 == T)`

`ind[0][-length:] = np.flip(ind[0][-length:])`

`ind[1][-length:] = np.flip(ind[1][-length:])`